# ASP.NET WebService Only returns one field of my customized class

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.NET WebService(In C#),and have a WebMethod like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public Class1 GetClass1(string Param1)
{
    return new Class1(Param1);
}
```

"Class1" is a customized Class with the following code:

```
public partial class Class1
{
    public Class1() { }
    public Class1(string Param1)
    {
        Prop1 = Param1;
    }
}

public partial class Class1
{
    public string Prop1
    {
        get
        {
            return _Prop1;
        }
        set 
        {
            _Prop1 = value;
            ----Code to Update Other 2 Properties----
            ----One is Like Below----
            _Prop2 = Get_Prop2_In_DataBase_By_Prop1(value);
        }
    }

    private string _Prop1 = "0";
}

public partial class Class1
{
    ----Other 2 Properties----
}
```

Now I called GetClass1,but it only returns Prop1.I want it to show all the public fields in Class1.What's the problem?

---Edited at 2017-6-20 15:15:00---

My code defining the other two Properties are like following:

```
public string Prop2
{
        get
        {
            return _Prop2;
        }
}
private string _Prop2 = "0";
```

Comment: This part is already working. Why don't you share some code blocks those not working?

Comment: @MuratSEKERMCT I think these codes can already describe the problem

Comment: Can you elaborate below part like how you declared other 2 properties?

          public partial class Class1
{
    ----Other 2 Properties----
}
       I tried like this 

public partial class Class1
        {
            public string prop2 { get; set; }
            public string prop3 { get; set; }
        }   the code works fine ...

Comment: @VigneshwaranMarkandan Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The properties must have a setter to be serialized which is necessary to be shown by a WebService.

Answer (score 0):

Thats why i asked you for the properties that you defined which was missed earlier.

```
public partial class Class1 
{ 
public string prop2 { get; set; }
public string prop3 { get; set; }
 }
```

As you mentioned you forgot setters !